# How many nodes in an AVL tree change depth after a rotation

Tags: algorithm, avl-tree

When adding or deleting a node in an AVL tree, rebalancing might occur. I can understand how there can be O(log(n)) rebalances needed, but when those rotations occur to balance the tree how many nodes actually change level. I can't seem to find this anywhere. I was thinking it was O(log(n)) but can't seem to figure out why. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: When adding, you only need one dual rotation, and three nodes get their balance factor updated. By dual rotation, I mean left-left, right-right, left-right, or right-left. Deleting is more complicated, and I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: Since Balance factor is the difference of heights of the 2 subtrees, couldn't any changes in depth cancel each other out? If both subtrees end up moving up a level the balance factor doesn't change, yet the depths of all of those nodes do. Or am I interpreting this wrong?

Comment: You can keep track of the height/depth of each node, or keep track of the balance factor, which is -1, 0, or 1. When the balance factor of a node reaches -2 or 2, a rotation is needed to restore the balance factor. Keeping track of balance factor instead of height/depth means that only the nodes involved in a rotation need their balance factors updated.

Comment: Note that's how it works when adding a node to the tree. When deleting a node, it may be necessary to perform rotations all the way up to the root of the tree, which will cause `logN` balance factors to get updated.

Comment: @user3386109 I was looking at the Wikipedia page for rotation and found that their diagrams include depth for the subtrees, and looking at them it looks like the number of nodes that change depth in the entire tree is linear after a rotation, assuming that each subtree is roughly the same size. Not sure if that's an accurate assumption, however. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Double_rotation

Comment: The pseudocode (`rotate_RightLeft`) that you linked is updating 3 balance factors: BF(X), BF(Y), and BF(Z). If that function is called after adding a node, then nothing more has to happen after the function returns. If the function is called after deleting a node, then the parent of Y needs to be checked, and another rotation may be needed. Potentially, rotations may be needed all the way up to the root of the tree.

Comment: I agree that up to 3 nodes need to change their BFs for adding, and up to log(n) for deleting, but the amount of nodes that change their depths is more than that. If you look at fig3 the t1, t2, and t3 subtrees all change their depth, right?

Comment: Right, t1, t2, and t3 all change their depth. But note that none of the nodes in those trees needs to have their balance factor updated. Balance factors are relative, so if the whole tree is moved, none of the balance factors within the tree change.

Comment: The thing the does matter is the height of the subtree. Initially X is the root, and X has a height of `h+2`. After the rotation, Y is the root, and Y has a height of `h+1`. So the overall height of the subtree has been reduced by 1. Which means the parent node (not shown) needs its balance factor updated. If X was the right child, subtract 1 from the parent's balance factor. If the parent's balance factor is now -2, the parent needs to be rotated.

Comment: @user3386109 thanks for the help. So to summarize, the number of BFs changed for adding is constant, while for deleting is log(n). While the number of nodes that change depth is linear for both adding/deleting? From what I've seen from the Wikipedia figure atleast.

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is O(n).
Suppose that at each node there is a "depth" field, how much will it cost to maintain it?

There is a theorem: If the information in field F of node N depends solely on its direct children, then it can be maintained when updated (-inserted or deleted) in logarithmic time.
(the theorem can be proved by induction)

The "depth" field doesn't depends on its children - but rather on its parent.

Note, however, that the theorem is one way, meaning it says when it can be maintained in logarithmic time, but doesn't say when not.Therefore it cant't be said with certaity that the "depth" field can be maintained in logarithmic time (such as height or BF fields), and it can even be seen at insertion that O(n) nodes change thier depth:

[image: Double rotation rotate_RightLeft]

In the first rotation the depth of t2 and t4 have been changed, and in the second, the depth of t1, t2, and t3!